# Возможно ли захватить замок и освободить его через timeout по-любому?

Tags: многопоточность, java

Есть некая активность, которую должны запускать несколько потоков. Запуск обязательно должен быть последовательным. Однако есть вероятность, что до освобождения замка выполнение не дойдет из-за ошибок. Дело в том, что по-хорошему освобождать замок надо в неких листенерах, когда на шину событий придет соответствующее сообщение.

Что я хочу: хочу получать замок с неким таймаутом, и если он превышен - отдавать замок следующему рабочему потоку.

Неужели в Джаве нет такой штуковины?

Если нет, то надо изобрести. Можно например захватывать Semaphore, а затем отпускать его через таймаут в другом потоке:

```
public class Test {   
    private static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);    
    void runit() throws InterruptedException {
        if (semaphore.tryAcquire(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
           doit();
        } else {
           semaphore.release();
           semaphore.acquire();
           doit();
        }
    }        
    void doit() {
        //do dangerous stuff
    }
}
```

Это ок? Есть варианты получше?

Comment: Извини, Марио, но твоя принцесса в другом замке.

Comment: Вы на самом деле не хотите то, чего вы хотите. Вам не нужно ничего отдавать. Если вам надо ждать какого-то сигнала, то зачем тогда вам держать блокировку всё это время? Отпускайте её как только начинаете ожидание этого сигнала.

Comment: Я посылаю некий запрос и жду его ответа. Архитектура такова что обработка двух запросов одновременно вызовет ошибки. Мне надо дождаться ответа на запрос, либо быть уверенным что исполнение провалилось. Никаких ошибок не будет выкинуто.

Answer (score 2):

- Надуманная какая-то проблема.
- Если все, что делает ваш метод `doit` всегда должно быть под `lock'ом`, то воспользуйтесь конструкцией `try-finally` или, что предпочтительнее, [пометьте метод как `synchronized`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019339/side-effects-of-throwing-an-exception-inside-a-synchronized-clause) Оба способа гарантируют снятие `lock'a` в случае возникновения исключительной ситуации.
- Если вы пытаетесь изобрести какой-то новый способ борьбы с `deadlock'ами`, то рекомендую начать с [изучения информации про `ReentrantLock`.](http://edgblog.wordpress.com/2008/02/16/avoiding-deadlocks-with-reentrantlock/)

Comment: Проблема в том, что метод doit() отправляет асинхронный запрос, и снятие замка должно происходить в его callback-e, однако он может не придти в случае ошибки.

Comment: @KutaBeach

- Опять вы что-то мудрите. Если обработчик каждого запроса должен быть потокобезопасным ("Архитектура такова что обработка двух запросов одновременно вызовет ошибки"), то пометьте код обработчика как synchronized. Если обработка такого запроса выкинет исключение, то `lock` будет снят и ничего страшного не произошло.

- Если в коде обработчика есть вызов некоторого `callback'a`, то засплиттите его на два метода - `synchronized ? processRequest(...)` и `void processRequestAndReportIt`. Во втором из них в `try-catch` вызовите `processRequest`, а дальше сихронно вызовите `callback`.

Comment: @KutaBeach И да, вы бы лучше начали с описания исходной задачи, наверняка все можно сделать намного проще.

Comment: Похоже у ТС стоит задача синхронизации запросов.

Видимо это решается через очередь на отправку запроса.

Comment: А нельзя попробовать `Thread.join(long millis)`, чтобы подождать выполнения потока, затем если поток не завершился убить его?

Comment: Сделать метод запуска запроса синхронизированным недостаточно - запросы запустятся один за другим и придут одновременно. Я также не понимаю как вы можете освободить замок в callback-e, который не придет.

Comment: avp вы правы, нужна очередь команд на последовательное выполение, однако если одна из них превысит таймаут - надо выполнять следующую.

Comment: Как workaround пойдет такое решение: к нам приходит поток запросов, мы пересылаем их последовательно через заданный интервал. Хотелось бы добиться прекращения ожидания интервала если от отосланного запроса пришел ответ ОК.

Comment: @KutaBeach, посмотрите в доку. 

IMHO правильное сочетание   wait(long timeout), notify() и tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit) поможет решить задачку.